# Graylog alerting on specific log occurrence

Tags: graylog

I have a question on how does one set up an email alert, when a certain error in found in the logs.
So basicly i have this sort of error :
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "something".

Now when this error, or similar error comes, i would love for graylog to alert certain people so they can react to it, however i have managed to only find information on how you set up alerts when there are too many messages coming through or something like that. If anyone has some experience with this sort of search and notify alert, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Graylog are you using?

Have you tried the docs here:

https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/alerts.html?highlight=alerts

[image: Graylog Filter Settings]

Set your query, stream, intervals and then select "Filter has results" and it will generate an event each time the query comes up with a match. You can then use a notification to send emails to relevant users.

Comment: Is this available for Graylog Community?

Answer (score 0):

When you set an alarm, in the "conditions" section you can see there are two options.

One option is to aggregate the occurencies and then trigger the alarm when they reach a treshold, the other option is to just trigger the alarm as soon as there is a single occurency (that you need to define).

I personally used this option and it works fine. I've attached a screenshot of what I see from my graylog, but if you need additional informations, this is the page from Graylog documentation. I think it's very well explained :)

https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/alerts.html

[image]